# Alternative On Delete Cascade

Tags: mysql, sql

there is an alternative constrain for "on delete cascade" where you can delete the information in parents table, then on the column child (automatically) but not the entirely info of the row?

I mean, i would like to keep the record in child table.

Comment: `on delete set null`